# Ruby: How can I read a CSV file that contains two headers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, csv

I have a ".CSV" file that I'm trying to parse using `CSV` in ruby.  The file has two rows of headers though and I've never encountered this before and don't know how to handle it.  Below is an example of the headers and rows.

**Row 1**

```
"Institution ID","Institution","Game Date","Uniform Number","Last Name","First Name","Rushing","","","","","Passing","","","","","","Total Off.","","Receiving","","","Pass Int","","","Fumble Ret","","","Punting","","Punt Ret","","","KO Ret","","","Total TD","Off xpts","","","","Def xpts","","","","FG","","Saf","Points"
```

**Row 2**

`"","","","","","","Rushes","Gain","Loss","Net","TD","Att","Cmp","Int","Yards","TD","Conv","Plays","Yards","No.","Yards","TD","No.","Yards","TD","No.","Yards","TD","No.","Yards","No.","Yards","TD","No.","Yards","TD","","Kicks Att","Kicks Made","R/P Att","R/P Made","Kicks Att","Kicks Made","Int/Fum Att","Int/Fum Made","Att","Made"`

**Row 3**

`"721","AirForce","09/01/12","19","BASKA","DAVID","","","","","","","","","","","","0","0","","","","","","","","","","2","85","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","0"`

There are no returns in the example above I just added them so it would be easier to read.  Does `CSV` have methods available to handle this structure or will I have to write my own methods to handle this?  Thanks!

Comment: In your example I can only see one header line, not two. Could you please post an example that shows more lines?

Comment: `"Institution ID"` starts the first header line. `"","","","","","","Rushes"` starts the second header line. Hope that helps clear it up.

Comment: the second header line contains 2 columns less than the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to write your own logic. CSV is really just rows and columns, and by itself has no inherent idea of what each column or row really is, it's just raw data. Thus, CSV has no concept or awareness that it has two header rows, that's a human thing, so you'll need to build your own heuristics.

Given that your data rows look like:

```
"721","Air Force","09/01/12",
```

When you start parsing your data, if the first column represents an integer, then, if you convert it to an int and if it's `> 0` than you know you're dealing with a valid "row" and not a header.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful.  I had looked through the Ruby CSV documentation and didn't see anything so I'm glad to see I'm not going blind!

Answer (score 9):

It looks like your CSV file was produced from an Excel spreadsheet that has columns grouped like this:

```
... |        Rushing        |         Passing         | ...
... |Rushes|Gain|Loss|Net|TD|Att|Cmp|Int|Yards|TD|Conv| ...
```

(Not sure if I restored the groups properly.)

There is no standard tools to work with such kind of CSV files, AFAIK. You have to do the job manually.

- Read the first line, treat it as first header line.
- Read the second line, treat it as second header line.
- Read the third line, treat it as first data line.
- ...

Comment: Great visual, well done. This is what OP probably should have done in the first place. And I agree with your recommendations - deal with it manually. I usually use `row.fetch( "Gain" )` to obtain the value of the column, but with this format, it may be best to use an index Hash like `columns = { "Institution ID" => 0, ... }` and then `row[ columns[ "Institution ID" ] ]`. Ugly but better than manually converting 100s of spreadsheets prior to import...

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend using the `smarter_csv` gem, and manually provide the correct headers:

```
 require 'smarter_csv'
 options = {:user_provided_headers => ["Institution ID","Institution","Game Date","Uniform Number","Last Name","First Name", ... provide all headers here ... ], 
            :headers_in_file => false}
 data = SmarterCSV.process(filename, options)
 data.pop # to ignore the first header line
 data.pop # to ignore the second header line
 # data now contains an array of hashes with your data
```

Please check the GitHub page for the options, and examples.
https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv

One option you should use is `:user_provided_headers` , and then simply specify the headers you want in an array. This way you can work around cases like this.

You will have to do `data.pop` to ignore the header lines in the file.

Comment: can you please upload a small sample CSV file somewhere? e.g. as a gist? Should be easy to add a feature to `smarter_csv` for that.

Comment: yes, I can try to auto-merge the two header-lines. The second line is two columns shorter than the first line.. weird

Comment: probably the easiest way to do this is to use the `:user_provided_headers` option in `smarter_csv`

Comment: cool I'll check it out. Yeah it's not formed well. I appreciate all the suggestions/help.

Answer (score 1):

[Read the CSV in](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) and skip the first line on output:

```
arr_of_arrs = CSV.read("path/to/file.csv")
arr_of_arrs[2..arr_of_arrs.length].each do |x|
   # operation here
end
```

Comment: `[1:]` - what syntax is this?

Comment: As noted in the edit, I got my python and ruby confused. Vote the answer down, if it makes you feel better.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[2..` instead of `[1..` ?

Comment: No, Mr Bolgov, ruby arrays are numbered from 0.

Comment: @hd1 Correct. Arrays are numbered from 0, and we need to skip 2 lines. `[1..` will skip only one while we need two. :-)

Comment: Instead of doing `[2..arr_of_arrs.length]` you could do `[2..-1]`, where `-1` is the last element in the Array. It's a lot cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: I believe this loads the entire CSV into memory at once so be weary if you're dealing with large CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy to do this with CSV. Just watch to see what the current line number is that's been read, and loop until you've read the headers:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('test.csv') do |row|
  next unless $. > 2
  puts "'" + row.join("', '") + "'"
end
```

When run this is what is output:

```
'721', 'Air Force', '09/01/12', '19', 'BASKA', 'DAVID', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '85', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0'
```

`$.` is the line-number of the last line read from the file that's opened. So, this immediately loops until `$.` has read two lines.

Comment: You can also use `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` to get the current row number, which I find to be a bit more explicit for yourself and others down the road.